# error in binding port "Address already in use" TCP socket programming in unix

Tags: c, sockets, unix, tcp

I've gone through many posts and forums and I'm new to socket programming. Major parts of my code are similar to 
[BIND ERROR : Address already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147592/bind-error-address-already-in-use/9206435#9206435)

but then i changed my code so that i include "setsockopt" function like so:

```
const char* port="5555";
int opt=1;
portno=atoi(port);
//parameters for server address
serv_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_port=htons(portno);
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
//bind the socket to the address
setsockopt(sockfd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,(const char *)&opt,sizeof(int));


 if(bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr))<0)
{close(sockfd);
error("error in binding port!");
}
```

But still i get the error. I have to close the terminal and restart it in order to use the port again. I want to use a hardcoded port (like i mentioned in the code above)

```
                                                            Thanks a lot in advance
```

Comment: Check the value returned by `setsockopt`.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a lingering process somewhere?

Comment: return value of setsockopt is 0 when the binding fails,however if the server is up then the return value is not displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A port number can only be used by one application at a time. That means you can not start the same program twice expecting both to bind to the same port.

The `SO_REUSEADDR` is for when the socket bound to an address has already been closed, the same address (ip-address/port pair) can be used again directly.

Comment: in my code (as mentioned above) i put the condition to close the socket in case the binding fails. Also I checked the return value of setsockopt which is 0.

Comment: @arvind In the comment to Eds answer you say that your program is still active. You have to stop the currently running program before you can run it again, just like I state in my answer. Port number can _not_ be shared by multiple programs.

Comment: so I have to kill it. Is there no way that I can reuse the port without killing it? isn't closing the file descriptor sufficient to close the connection and reuse it?

Comment: @arvind Yes, closing the socket should be enough.

Comment: but in my code, the condition is that if the binding fails then i used close the file descriptor "close(sockfd)" issue an error "error in binding" and then exit won't that take care of the closing the socket for me? the way i see it, the program when re-executed should one time give an error close the socket but upon another re-execution should work fine. But it doesn't. Please help me

Comment: @arvind That only closes the socket in the program that _fails_ to bind, not the already running program!

Answer (score 3):

Check to see if the port is in use. Either `telnet` to that port or use `netstat -a`. It should be in use (as the error indicates) and kill the appropriate process. Perhaps using `ps` to find the process.

Comment: netstat -natp displayed that my server is still active               tcp   0  0 0.0.0.0:5555  0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN      24328/server