# Error on binding: Address already in use

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, webserver

When I am trying to reuse the socket address this error is coming. I googled it and i got from this link [BIND ERROR : Address already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2147592/539472)

that i should call

```
setsockopt(SO_REUSEADDR)
```

but after doing this its not working fine.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even when using `SO_REUSEADDR` you can't have multiple bindings to a single address/port pair, that's not what `SO_REUSEADDR` does.

See e.g. [this link](http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/4.5.shtml) for a good explanation of the flag.

Comment: yes i got the problem. Actually i was performing a `fork()` operation, which was spawning child processes. And I was stopping parent process. The child processes were still running and i was getting that `Error: Address already in use`. Anyways thanks for that  link as well. It did help me. :)